# How to determine brakes on steering wheel controller vertical axis

Tags: input, unity-game-engine, game-physics, joystick

So in every game engine I program, with a steering controller, the gas is positive values on the Y-axis and the brakes are negative values.  Basically, pressing the gas sends a Y value of 0 to 1, and pressing the brake sends 0 to -1.

How can I tell if the brake is pressed at the same time as the accelerator?  A value of .5 could mean the gas pedal part way down, or all the way down with some brake applied.

Is there a way to determine if the brake is pressed?